# Additional EntityID or Binding on a Single ADFS Server?

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, adfs2.0

I'm a programmer with ***VERY*** limited system experience, and I've set up an ADFS 2.0 Rollup 3 server for authentication to Salesforce.

My use cases are:
1. Allow single users to authenticate against their NameID in the UPN.
2. Allow group users to authenticate by membership in a user group.

I would like to have both types of authentication on the same ADFS server.  Here is an example of the sign-on screen, where the "Active Directory" button is for single users, and the "Admin Users" are members of a user group.

[image: This is an example of the two buttons for single user or group user sign-on]

I have no problem with either group authentication or user authentication on a single ADFS server, but I'd like both on the same ADFS server for a single relying party trust.  However, I haven't been able to get that to work.

The entityID is the default,

```
http://[Server Name]/adfs/services/trust
```

The login URL is the SAML 2.0 endpoint:

```
https://[Server Name]/adfs/ls/
```

I've tried several things that didn't work:

SalesForce requires the "issuer" (in this case, the entityID) and the "login URL" together are unique, so I've tried adding URL parameters to the login URL, since those will get imported into ADFS from the metadata file.  That doesn't work though - If I have two relying party trusts, one w/ the parameters, and one without, I'll get signed into one, regardless of which one I'm trying to sign into.

I've also tried adding multiple rules to one, but that generates an error when I try for SSO.

How could I get this to work?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case i.e. "either group authentication or user authentication"? ADFS has only one EntityID and it's not dynamic.

Comment: @nzpcmad - Sure - I have two types of user accounts in SalesForce (the relying party trust).  If they are group accounts, you must be a member of a user group to sign into that account, and if it's a single user account, it uses the NameID of the UPN.  For each type of sign-on, there's a button that corresponds to the identity provider, which initiates the SAML request.

Comment: OK - so for single user, just use a Transform NameID rule. What claims to you need to pass for the group accounts?

Comment: @nzpcmad - Sorry for the slow reply - I saw this at the EOD.  I'm not sure what is initially sent - ADFS responds with a NameID that I define.  I followed the basic setup under this [page](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_with_Force.com_and_Microsoft_Active_Directory_Federation_Services) - At the "Configuration" section, about 1/4 way down

Comment: Nowhere in that article is "group" even mentioned so to repeat - What claims to you need to pass for the group accounts?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I provided that as a reference for SalesForce's setup and a level of commonality.  I figured out the group stuff on my own, but it wasn't much of a leap.  For the group account, I define a Federation ID on the relying party trust.  On ADFS, I provide a token that matches the Federation ID.  When you click the button, ADFS uses the endpoint and the current user's AD info to check against the rules for that relying party trust.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever stumbles across this, in order for this to work, the simplest solution is to send different relying party IDs from SalesForce, and have different relying party trusts in ADFS.

In SalesForce, this would appear as two different buttons on the login screen, and in ADFS, this would appear as two different relying parties - One in each system for each relying party ID.

If you are auto-signing in from some application, you'll have to iterate over each relying party trust, and try to authenticate from each.

I can't imagine this very specific use case will be much value, so comment if you want more details, since my 3 year old question has little interest :)